# extract string from a file using shell script

Tags: string, unix, shell, extract

I have file called log.txt. file contains are like below :-

```
/proc
used    avail
10      100
```

how can i extract the below strings from that file using shell script. I want the below strings to be extracted.

```
/proc
10
100
```

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the most useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on your existing questions.

Comment: Following your comments on Eric's answer and my own, could you please edit your question to include the *actual* contents of `log.txt` as well as your *actual* expected output rather than expecting the StackOverflow community to guess. Thanks ever-so!

Comment: Aha. Thanks @dogbane. A little formatting makes the World of difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1 $4 $5}' log.txt
```

Comment: thx, but actually the file content is not like above. its like :- In the first line its only /proc. in the second line its "used" and "avail" and in the next line "10" and "100". below "used" its "10" and below "avail" its "100". the structure is like this. hope u can uderstand what i want to describe here

Comment: please have a look at my question in 1st page(scroll up)... ur answer is not working for that

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\/proc/ {print;getline;getline;print $1"\n"$2}' log.txt
```

The above `awk` command calls `getline` twice whenever a line matches `/proc`. The `print` statement then prints out the second line after the match.

**Output:**

```
/proc
10
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, and if it is spaces you have between 10 and 100:

```
sed -e '2d;3s/  */\n/' log.txt
```

if it is tabs you have between 10 and 100, and you gave GNU sed:

```
sed -e '2d;3s/\t\t*/\n/' log.txt
```

if it is tabs you have between 10 and 100, and you do not have gave GNU sed, but real tabs instead of the 2 \t above.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding sed (or awk) and using standard UNIX utilities, and if it is spaces you have between 10 and 100:

```
paste -s -d " " file | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1,4,5 | tr " " "\n"
```

if it is tabs you have between 10 and 100, and you have GNU utilities:

```
paste -s -d "\t" file | tr -s "\t" | cut -f 1,4,5 | tr "\t" "\n"
```

if it is tabs you have between 10 and 100, and you do not have gave GNU utilities, but real tabs instead of the \t above and a real  instead of the \n.